# Choosing one text value over the other

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table similar as below:

```
  store    manager      status         
    1       tim          good  
    2       anna         good
    3       ben          bad  
    4       tim          bad
    5       tim          ok
```

My goal is to have the desired output as below. I want to display the status for each manager. The order preference would be `bad > ok > good`. Therefore, if a manager (tim) has 3 different store statuses, it will take `bad` as the final status.

```
    manager       status         
      tim          bad
      anna         good
      ben          bad
```

I cannot think of a creative solution to choose one value over the other, so I would really appreciate if anyone could give me a suggestion/approach on how to tackle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is aggregation with conditional logic like this:

```
select manager,
       coalesce(max(case when status = 'bad' then status end),
                max(case when status = 'ok' then status end),
                max(case when status = 'good' then status end)
               )
from t
group by manager;
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by manager
                                order by case status when 'bad'  then 1 when 'ok' then 2 when 'good' then 3 else 4 end
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not think of the COALESE (MAX()) function at all this is great!